# Reviving an expired corporation

Tags: corporate-law, nevada

Is there a procedure that allows the reviving of an expired LLC in Nevada? The company in question expired over a year ago after the required annual documents were not filed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Most states have a reinstatement period of up to five years during which you can reinstate your corporation by filing the appropriate paperwork and paying the required fees and any penalties (extra fees) due.

Check the website of your state's corporation authority for the exact procedure.

In Nevada, it looks like the Secretary of State is the right place to go. [There website link is here](http://nvsos.gov/index.aspx?page=420).

Comment: Thank you! I had searched the secretary of state site before without finding an answer - your use of the term "reinstatement" gave me the right clue and I was able to find the information rapidly.